# Symfony 3, get form name value including brackets

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, brackets

I have a form which indludes

```
<input type="hidden" name="transportation[go][when]">
```

And I would like to get the name attribut in my controller with a:

```
$when = $request->request->get('when');
```

Is there a way to get this name attribute?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your request is `POST`:

```
$request->request->get('transportation')['go']['when'];
```

If your request is `GET`:

```
$request->query->get('transportation')['go']['when'];
```

Here data passing as `array`.

Comment: Super, thank you ! Exactly what I needed, and hard to find this information

Comment: @sim100, you are welcome. I am always #SOReadyToHelp!